# MultiValueDictKeyError at / 'username' //DJango beginners project

Tags: python-3.x, django

**strong text**I was trying to do CRM on Django tutorial from freecodecamp and completed it but there is an error at the addRecord page for me, which says

**in terminal**
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\desktop\personaldump\python\django\virt\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 84, in **getitem**
list_ = super().**getitem**(key)
KeyError: 'username'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\desktop\personaldump\python\django\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\desktop\personaldump\python\django\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\desktop\personaldump\python\django\virt\Scripts\CRM\first\views.py", line 10, in home
username=request.POST['username']
File "C:\Users\desktop\personaldump\python\django\virt\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 86, in **getitem**
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'username'
[02/May/2023 23:40:34] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 81254

**on the server when I try to add record**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUraW.png)

````
    return render(request,'home.html',{'records':records})


I tried changing my username from 
```
def home(request):
    records= Record.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"login successful")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "login failed")
            return redirect('home')
        
    return render(request,'home.html',{'records':records})
**to**
def home(request):
    records= Record.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"login successful")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "login failed")
            return redirect('home')
```
````

if I do that I am directing getting a "login failed" message when Adding a record

home.html

```
            {%extends 'base.html'%}
        {%block content%}
        {%if user.is_authenticated%}
          <h1>Records</h1>
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">City</th>
                <th scope="col">State</th>
                <th scope="col">Zipcode</th>
                <th scope="col">Created At</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
          {% if records %}
            {% for record in records %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.state }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.zipcode }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.created_at }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'record' record.id %}">{{ record.id }}</a></td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          
          {% endif %}
          
            
              </tbody>
            </table>
        {%else%}
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="post" action="{%url 'home'%}">
            {% csrf_token%}
           
                <div class="mb-3">
        
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username", placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password", placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        {%endif%}
        {%endblock%}
    
**addrecord.html**
  

      {%extends 'base.html'%}
        {%block content%}
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        
        <h1>Add Record</h1>
            <form method="post" action="{%url 'home'%}">
            {% csrf_token%}
                {{form.as_p}}
        
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">ADD</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        {%endblock%}
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Record
from django import forms

class Signup(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(label='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email Address'}))
    FullName=forms.CharField(label='',max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Full Name'}))

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields={'username','password1','password2','email','FullName'}


def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(Signup,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'User Name'
    self.fields['username'].label = ''
    self.fields['username'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small></br>Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small></span>'

    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
    self.fields['password1'].label = ''
    self.fields['password1'].help_text = '<ul class="form-text text-muted small"><li>Your password can\'t be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can\'t be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can\'t be entirely numeric.</li></ul>'

    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'
    self.fields['password2'].label = ''
    self.fields['password2'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Enter the same password as before, for verification.</small></span>'

class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Full Name", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Phone", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    address = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Address", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    city = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"City", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    state = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"State", "class":"form-control"}), label="")
    zipcode = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Zipcode", "class":"form-control"}), label="")

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        exclude = ("user",)
```

**I am only getting this error when Adding a new record not when trying to log in.**

Comment: Share the HTML form.

Comment: I am getting the error when trying to add a record
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLxSwtkWG0VPqZnkrGkXKN1i2NmIDqHw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma at the end of the name, there should be no comma, so `name="username"`, not <s>`name="username",`</s>:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
…
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

---

**Note**: Please use `request.POST['username']` over `request.POST.get('username')`. Using `.get(…)` often only silences the error, but not the problem: indeed it will work if the key is missing. But if the value for that key is really required, it will only result in more trouble later in the process.

---

**Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Comment: comma did not fix the issue, when am trying to add a record it is failing at
def home(request):
    records= Record.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"login successful")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "login failed")
   we are getting this "login failed".

Comment: @ShaikShahidAfridi: how did you register the user in the first place. *Don't* use `request.POST.get`, it is horrible code design.

Comment: def home(request):
    records= Record.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"login successful")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "login failed")
            return redirect('home')
still getting "login failed", when trying to enter a new record

Comment: @ShaikShahidAfridi: please [[edit]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76157878/67579) the question if you want to share code, also include the view where you *register* the user. Do you get the error only when adding data, or when logging in as well?

Comment: **I am only getting this error when Adding a new record not when trying to log in.**

Comment: @ShaikShahidAfridi: where do you pass the form to the template? What view do you use to add a new record?